# Polyline Intersection With Terrain in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I am using Cesium, and am trying to detect where a polyline intersects with the terrain on the Earth. I have a polyline that begins at some point in the air and is drawn towards the Earth at a certain angle.

Right now I am calculating the end point just using a set distance, so I have a start and endPoint. I want to detect where this polyline first hits the Earth's surface and stop drawing it at that point. For example, if there is a tall mountain, I don't want the line to continue on the other side of the mountain.

I've tried a few different approaches using `IntersectionTests`, specifically the `grazingAltitudeLocation` and `rayEllipsoid` but have not had any luck. I have been creating a ray with the start and end points of my polyline and then using the `viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid` as the ellipsoid in the functions. I keep getting the starting point returned as the intersection point.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong, or suggestions on a different way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is edited/added content

Here is the code I used, `grazingAltitudeLocation` returns the start point and `rayEllipsoid` returns undefined.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;
var globe = scene.globe;
var ellipsoid = scene.globe.ellipsoid;
var primitives = scene.primitives;

globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;

var cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles'});
scene.terrainProvider = cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes;

var startLon = -117.69;
var startLat = 35.69;
var startElv = 20000;
var endLon = -120.0417;
var endLat = 39.0917;
var endElv = 0;

var startCart = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(startLon, startLat, startElv);
var start = ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(startCart);

var endCart = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(endLon, endLat, endElv);
var end = ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(endCart);

var ray = new Cesium.Ray(start, end);

var intersection = Cesium.IntersectionTests.grazingAltitudeLocation(ray, ellipsoid);

var intersection2 = Cesium.IntersectionTests.rayEllipsoid(ray, ellipsoid);
var point = Cesium.Ray.getPoint(ray, intersection2.start);
```

Comment: Is the only purpose of calculating the intersection point to avoid displaying the polyline under the Earth's surface? Can you show your unsuccessful code with `rayEllipsoid`? If you don't really care about calculating this point but just want to avoid displaying the portion of polyline underneath the Earth's surface, did you try [`Globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Globe.html#depthTestAgainstTerrain)?

Comment: The purpose of finding it is to use that as the end point of the polyline.  The depthTestAgainstTerrain does work for not displaying it under the Earth's surface, but if it goes through a mountain, it continues to draw on the other side.  I want to be able to set the end point so it just stops at the mountain.  I've added the code above.

Comment: Isn't the second parameter of `Ray` constructor supposed to be

Comment: ... the "direction"? Which means the *vector* direction: `end - start`, in your case, I suppose. This is what the `Ray` reference says.

Comment: Ok, I tried and it works fine with `var dir = new Cesium.Cartesian3(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y, end.z - start.z); var ray = new Cesium.Ray(start, dir);`: `point` is no longer `undefined`. However, this is still not what you want: `point` is the intersection with the ellipsoid and not the terrain. In order to check this statement, just `console.log(point); console.log(end);`: they are approximately the same because `endElv` is 0;

Comment: If you found the answer. please add it as an answer to the question. THanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do [picking on Globe](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Globe.html#pick), not on the Ellipsoid.
Hope this would help:

```
function pickGlobeIntersection(viewer, p0, p1) {
      //all positions are in Cartesian3
      var direction = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
      Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(p1, p0, direction);
      Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(direction, direction);

      var ray = new Cesium.Ray(p0, direction);
      var hitPos = viewer.scene.globe.pick(ray, viewer.scene);

      if ((hitPos !== undefined) && (hitPos !== null)) {
        return hitPos;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
}
```

Regards