# Run custom Cesium function only after viewer.zoomTo() has been executed

Tags: promise, cesiumjs, terrain

I have a [CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/cesiumjs/) function that I want to be executed after and only after having performed a [zoomTo()](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Viewer.html#zoomTo), which makes me sure the terrain has been fully loaded (as stated in the doc)!
It's because this function should actually [compute the intersection between a ray and the terrain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373300/polyline-intersection-with-terrain-in-cesium), so the terrain has to be fully loaded for its execution to be successful.

In the current state, the following code returns: `null` super quickly (it doesn't wait at all for the terrain):

e.g.:

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    imageryProvider : new Cesium.BingMapsImageryProvider({
        url : 'https://dev.virtualearth.net',
        key : $(BING_KEY),
        mapStyle : Cesium.BingMapsStyle.AERIAL
    }),
    terrainProvider: new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : 'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/terrain-quantized-mesh/?key$(MKEY)'
    });
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    infoBox : false,
});

var p0 = [10.7465, 48.3147, 1500];
var p1 = [10.7475, 48.3127, 1000];
var start = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(...p0);
var end = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(...p1);

var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    polyline : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([
            ...(p0.concat(p1))
        ]),
        width : 4,
        material : new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
            glowPower : 1,
            color : Cesium.Color.GREEN
        })
    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);

// then run this function:
function pickGlobeIntersection(viewer, p0, p1) {
      var direction = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
      Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(p1, p0, direction);
      console.log("direction: ", direction);
      Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(direction, direction);

      var ray = new Cesium.Ray(p0, direction);
      var hitPos = viewer.scene.globe.pick(ray, viewer.scene);

      if ((hitPos !== undefined) && (hitPos !== null)) {
        console.log("hitPos: ", hitPos);
        return hitPos;
      } else {
        console.log("hitPos is null!");
        return null;
      }
}

pickGlobeIntersection(viewer, start, end);
```

(replace the viewer by the default one if code is used in the [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/))

How can I make sure the function is executed only after the terrain has been fully loaded?

Comment: `viewer.zoomTo(target, offset)` returns Promise, therefore you might try `viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities)
.then(bool => {
 if(bool) {
  pickGlobeIntersection(viewer, start, end);
 } else {
  // hmmmm!
 }
});`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 just what I was looking for! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Pleased to help @Mango C. No idea why I didn't write a proper answer. Sept 2020 seems like a lifetime ago.